# Sum nested lists in Python

Tags: python

I have a nested list in python, `i=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`. I want to sum the terms such that the final result is `j=[1+4,2+5,6+3]`. I have tried:

```
i=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
j=[sum(x) for x in zip(i)]
```

But this is what I get instead:

```
>>>print j
[6, 15]
```

Comment: Of course both answers are correct. I have to give credit to the first one though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` does not take a `list` of `list`s as an argument. It takes an arbitrary long list of `list` arguments.

Here is how to do it:

```
i=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
j=[sum(x) for x in zip(*i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `*`

```
>>> i=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*i)]
[5, 7, 9]
```